# How to prevent Edit from displaying value defined during Create

Tags: react-admin

In short, the question is, how do I force React Admin to always render input values in an Edit form according to the state of the data returned from the API?

Background Info:

In my user create & edit forms, I have a password field.

My API never returns a password key/value.

After User Create, I am redirected to User Edit and the password input is filled in with the password I set in the create form, not the value from the API response.

This is not desired.

I presume this is all due to React Admin's "optimistic rendering"... but in the case of the user edit form, I would always like React Admin to respect the state of the data coming from the API.

I've set mutationMode to "pessimistic", but this does not effect the input values when redirected from Create, and Create has no "mutationMode".

So, anyone know how to always force Edit to pull its data from the API response?

Answer (score 0):

Set the input field type to "password": `<TextInput source="pass" type="password" />`

Comment: I'm already using <PasswordInput>... it seems the payload from the create action is being passed forward to the Edit form.

Answer (score 0):

React-admin stores the response of the `dataProvider.create()` in its cache for optimistic rendering. If you say that your API doesn't return the password, is it possible that your `dataProvider` *merges* the API response with the input data? That would explain the presence of the password.

Comment: I observe similar behavior: there is no password in the server response, dataProvider returns data only from the server response,
if you don't set the field type: type="password" the password is displayed.

Comment: Well, I'm already using <PasswordInput>, so I wouldn't expect to have to add type="password"? This video shows the issue, the response to create from the server does not have a password key, nor does the response to edit: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/12006639?key=6d1ffbce47635439f699c6e6b61d04ec

The only thing I can think is that for some reason the payload from the create request is being utilized in the Edit.

Comment: Again, check your `dataProvider.create()` call. Does it, by any chance, use the input to populate the output?